# Warning: implicit declaration of function ‘read’ ('write')

Tags: c, gcc, компилятор, warning

Почему компилятор выбрасывает warning при использовании read и write?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
n = read(newsockfd, &buffer, (size_t *) tmp_size);
...
n = write(newsockfd, "Hi!", (size_t *) 3);
...

gcc -Wall -o "server" "server.c"
server.c: In function ‘main’:
server.c:74:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘read’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
server.c:85:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘write’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
Compilation finished successfully.
```

Из перевода понятно, что произошла неявная декларация функции. Получается, что у меня не хватает какого-то includ'a?

Comment: @Din, в man function обычно пишут, какие include нужны.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это особенность С компилятора. Он может игнорировать тот факт, что нет прототипа, но если при линковке найдет подходящий символ, то все слинкует. А вот будет ли работать - не известно, так как прототип неизвестен и может произойти ЧП со стеком. В данном случае нужно добавить `#include <unistd.h>`