# Warning: implicit declaration of function

Tags: linux, c, gcc, компилятор

Изучаю утилиту make в Linux. Есть 4 файла в котором две функции, главная функция и Makefile(скриншоты ниже). При вызове утилиты make, появляется сообщение Warning: implicit declaration of function. Из-за чего это и что нужно исправить или сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function

Comment: @Эникейщик, вроде есть ссылка и на-поближе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/213706/178576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Очень** Вас прошу - **никогда** не помещайте в вопрос скриншоты. Как прикажите из этих скриншотов доставать куски Вашего кода?! С помощью OCR ?

По сути...

В файл main.c нужно добавить ( в самое начало, срозу после *#inclde*) описание Ваших внешних функций:

```
void print_hello();
int sum(int x, int y);
```

Компилятор Вам и говорит - что нет **явного** описания функций и он использует дефолтное описание.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! Я просто делаю все  это на виртуальной машине и не мог просто скопировать код, но в дальнейшем этого не повторится!